# VBA if file not found create and paste data

Tags: vba, excel, copy-paste

I hope you can help. I have a piece of code see CODE 1 (my code in its entirety) and essentially what it does is allows a user to navigate through folders, select a file. Once selected, it separates the workbook based on the criteria (country) in Column A into new worksheets, renames the new worksheets after the countries and adds some text. All this works fine.

The issue I am facing is that when the Workbook is split into different sheets. See Pic 1, I then need to copy and paste specific country sheets into workbooks already stored in another folder. See Pic 2. The code I have works fine if the workbook already exists in the folder (in my example Germany) but if the workbook is not present (Belgium)  I need the code to create a new workbook for that country and then paste the data into the new workbook.

So in Pic 2 you can see that Germany is present in folder `H:\TOV Storage Folder`
and the copy and paste code see CODE 2 works fine

CODE 2

```
If s.Name = "DE_ITOV_MTNG_ATNDEE.xlsx" Then

            s.Activate
            ActiveSheet.Range("A1", ActiveCell.SpecialCells(xlLastCell)).Copy
            Set y = Workbooks.Open("H:\TOV Storage Folder\Germany.xlsx")
            y.Sheets(2).Name = "DE_ITOV_MTNG_ATNDEE"
            y.Sheets("DE_ITOV_MTNG_ATNDEE").Range("A1").PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteFormulas
            y.SaveAs "H:\TOV Storage Folder\Germany.xlsx"
            y.Close
```

But Belgium does not exist in folder `H:\TOV Storage Folder` so CODE 3 throws back an error saying cannot find Belgium in `H:\TOV Storage Folder` and the macro stops

CODE 3

```
ElseIf s.Name = "BE_ITOV_MTNG_ATNDEE.xlsx" Then
            s.Activate
            ActiveSheet.Range("A1", ActiveCell.SpecialCells(xlLastCell)).Copy
            Set y_1 = Workbooks.Open("H:\TOV Storage Folder\Belgium.xlsx")
            y_1.Sheets(2).Name = "BE_ITOV_MTNG_ATNDEE"
            y_1.Sheets("BE_ITOV_MTNG_ATNDEE").Range("A1").PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteFormulas
            y_1.SaveAs "H:\TOV Storage Folder\Belgium.xlsx"
            y_1.Close
```

Essentially what I need to happen is for the workbook to split in to its country sheets then for the macro to start moving through the sheets if it finds a country sheet that has a corresponding workbook present in `H:\TOV Storage Folder` then perform the copy and paste, if it finds a sheet in the split workbook that does not have a corresponding country in `H:\TOV Storage Folder` then create one and perform the paste and move onto the next country sheet in the split workbook and repeat process.

In a very simple way I need the macro to 
search through the split sheets and go "Ah I have found France FR_ITOV_MTNG_ATNDEE.xlsx and you have a workbook in  `H:\TOV Storage Folder` copy, paste, next sheet, ah I found Latvia LV_ITOV_MTNG_ATNDEE.xlsx you do not have a workbook in `H:\TOV Storage Folder`  create workbook for Latvia, copy ,paste! and so on.

I apologies if my question is lengthy I just want to make my issue transparent.

Can my code be amended to solve my issue?

As always any and all help is greatly appreciate.

CODE 1

```
    Sub Make_Macro_Go_now()

Dim my_FileName As Variant

    MsgBox "Pick your TOV file" '<--| txt box for prompt to pick a file

        my_FileName = Application.GetOpenFilename(FileFilter:="Excel Files,*.xl*;*.xm*") '<--| Opens the file window to allow selection

    If my_FileName <> False Then
    Workbooks.Open FileName:=my_FileName


Call Filter_2 '<--|Calls the Filter Code and executes

End If


End Sub

Public Sub Filter_2()


    'Optimize Macro Speed
  Application.ScreenUpdating = False
  Application.EnableEvents = False
  Application.Calculation = xlCalculationManual

    Dim rCountry As Range, helpCol As Range

    Dim FileName As String
    Dim s As Worksheet

Dim y As Workbook ''AT
Dim y_1 As Workbook ''BE


    FileName = Right(ActiveWorkbook.Name, 22)

    With ActiveWorkbook.Sheets(1) '<--| refer to data worksheet
        With .UsedRange
            Set helpCol = .Resize(1, 1).Offset(, .Columns.Count) '<--| get a "helper" column just at the right of used range, it'll be used to store unique country names in
        End With

        With .Range("A1:Q" & .Cells(.Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row) '<--| refer to its columns "A:Q" from row 1 to last non empty row of column "A"
            .Columns(1).AdvancedFilter Action:=xlFilterCopy, CopyToRange:=helpCol, Unique:=True '<-- call AdvancedFilter on 6th column of the referenced range and store its unique values in "helper" column
            Set helpCol = Range(helpCol.Offset(1), helpCol.End(xlDown)) '<--| set range with unique names in (skip header row)
            For Each rCountry In helpCol '<--| iterate over unique country names range (skip header row)
                .AutoFilter 1, rCountry.Value2 '<--| filter data on country field (6th column) with current unique country name
                If Application.WorksheetFunction.Subtotal(103, .Cells.Resize(, 1)) > 1 Then '<--| if any cell other than header ones has been filtered...
                    Worksheets.Add Worksheets(Worksheets.Count) '<--... add new sheet
                    ActiveSheet.Name = rCountry.Value2 & FileName  '<--... rename it

                    .SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible).Copy ActiveSheet.Range("A1") 'copy data for country under header



                End If
            Next
        End With
        .AutoFilterMode = False '<--| remove autofilter and show all rows back




    End With
    helpCol.Offset(-1).End(xlDown).Clear '<--| clear helper column (header included)

   ''Copy and Paste Data
   For Each s In Sheets
        If s.Name = "DE_ITOV_MTNG_ATNDEE.xlsx" Then

            s.Activate
            ActiveSheet.Range("A1", ActiveCell.SpecialCells(xlLastCell)).Copy
            Set y = Workbooks.Open("H:\TOV Storage Folder\Germany.xlsx")
            y.Sheets(2).Name = "DE_ITOV_MTNG_ATNDEE"
            y.Sheets("DE_ITOV_MTNG_ATNDEE").Range("A1").PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteFormulas
            y.SaveAs "H:\TOV Storage Folder\Germany.xlsx"
            y.Close

            ElseIf s.Name = "BE_ITOV_MTNG_ATNDEE.xlsx" Then
            s.Activate
            ActiveSheet.Range("A1", ActiveCell.SpecialCells(xlLastCell)).Copy
            Set y_1 = Workbooks.Open("H:\TOV Storage Folder\Belgium.xlsx")
            y_1.Sheets(2).Name = "BE_ITOV_MTNG_ATNDEE"
            y_1.Sheets("BE_ITOV_MTNG_ATNDEE").Range("A1").PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteFormulas
            y_1.SaveAs "H:\TOV Storage Folder\Belgium.xlsx"
            y_1.Close



            ''Exit Sub
        End If

    Next s
    ''MsgBox "Sheet a does not exist"

    ''End If
    'Message Box when tasks are completed
  MsgBox "Task Complete!"

ResetSettings:
  'Reset Macro Optimization Settings
    Application.EnableEvents = True
    Application.Calculation = xlCalculationAutomatic
    Application.ScreenUpdating = True

End Sub

Public Function DoesFileExist(ByVal sFile)
    Dim oFSO As New FileSystemObject
    If oFSO.FileExists(sFile) Then
        DoesFileExist = True
    Else
        DoesFileExist = False
    End If
End Function
```

Pic 1
[image]

Pic 2
[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the function below to check if the file exists before attempting to open the workbook. If it doesn't then create a workbook, otherwise open the existing workbook

```
Public Function DoesFileExist(ByVal sFile)
    Dim oFSO As New FileSystemObject
    If oFSO.FileExists(sFile) Then
        DoesFileExist = True
    Else
        DoesFileExist = False
    End If
End Function
```

You will need to add **`Microsoft Scription Runtime'** reference for the above function to work

Comment: Something I have done in the past is to have a blank workbook file and create a short function that copies the blank file to create a new workbook

Comment: Hi guys thank you for taking the time to respond it is greatly appreciated. @Zac I have added the function code you supplied to the end of my code and tick the box in references for `Microsoft Scription Runtime' but the macro is still not completing. Have I missed something? Again thank you for the help

Comment: You will have to be a bit more specific then that :). Are you getting an error? If so, what's the error? and what line does it occur on?

Comment: Hi Zac: The error is happening on line `Set y_1 = Workbooks.Open("H:\TOV Storage Folder\Belgium.xlsx")` and the error is saying it cannot find the folder .

Comment: Can you update your code to show where you added the call to this function. Likelihood is that the file doesn't exist. In which case you will have to create the workbook first

Comment: Hi Zac. I have edited my code above to show where the function is located. Please let me know if I can assist in any other way and thank you for the help :-)

Comment: You have added the function but you haven't made the call to the function to check if the file exists. Just before your statement `Set y = Workbooks.Open("H...` and `Set y_1 = Workbooks.Open("H...`, you have to make the call to this function with an `IF` condition as: `If DoesFileExist("H:\TOV Storage Folder\Belgium.xlsx") Then`. If it returns true, set your workbook as you are (i.e. `Set y_1 = Workbooks.Open("H:\TOV Storage Folder\Belgium.xlsx`). If it returns a false, you then have to create the workbook

Comment: BOO YEAH!! you the man Zac. :-) you have some serious VBA Kung Fu my friend thank you so much for the help. It is greatly appreciated. Much respect from Dublin :-)

Comment: No worries mate, glad it helped